# How to call Smali in Java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk, smali

I want to use [Java to smali plugin](https://github.com/ollide/intellij-java2smali), but I have to compile Java to class first, this is impossible for project like this

[image]

The `h.m` is

[image]

Javac don't understand this, but I just want to compile this java code to class, so I can convert it to smali.

This project is decode by `apktool d my.apk`, I try to inject some code in it, writing smali is harder than java.But I alread done the Inject part,just want to know how to compile java to class.

```
$ adb logcat -s "Injected"
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system
07-10 19:32:24.013  7689  7689 W Injected: Started
07-10 19:32:24.015  7689  7689 W Injected: Init
```

**EDIT**

The original title is `In Jetbrain can I just compile Java to class and ignore all error?`,but want I want is `How to call Smali in Java`, so I rename the title.

Comment: What about writing a dummy Java class with the same name as `h`variable and fields `l` and `m` like in smali? Then you'll be able to compile your original code file to class and discard the one generated for the dummy.

Comment: There is too much dummy class to write, so I chose [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38298127/1870054)

Comment: Haven't noticed the second answer is yours. Possibly it should be the accepted one.

Comment: @JesusFreke's answer closer to the original title `In Jetbrain can I just compile Java to class and ignore all error?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Java *requires* the definitions of the classes/methods/fields being used in a java program to be able to compile it. Without this information, it doesn't have enough information to be able to produce a class file.

For example, let's say you're trying to compile this program:

```
public class Main {
    public static int main(String[] args) {
        Blort blort = new Blort();
        blort.blarg("blurg!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The exact bytecode that is produced depends on the definition of the Blort.blarg method.

If blarg is defined like this:

```
public class Blort {
    public void blarg(String blah) {
        System.out.println(blah);
    }
}
```

Then the method call to blarg would be complied to:

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, LBlort;->blarg(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

However, if the blarg method is defined differently:

```
public class Blort {
    public void blarg(CharSequence blah) {
        System.out.println(blah);
    }
}
```

Then the method call would be compiled to:

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, LBlort;->blarg(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
```

These two method calls refer to different methods and are not interchangable. And if the compiler doesn't know at least the declaration of the blarg method, then it can't know the correct method signature to use.

And that's just 1 small example of why the compiler needs to know the definitions of all classes that are being referred to in a java program. There are many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Java can not do that, but here is a workaround that will work perfectly well.

1. Find the `classes.dex`
2. Use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) convert it to jar
3. Add jar to project
4. Now you can call smali code directly in your code.

   ```
   unzip my.apk -d apk
   d2j-dex2jar my/classes.dex
   # Add classes-dex2jar.jar to project
   ```